# PHP Regex explode the string using ',' except ',' inside quote and double qoute

Tags: php, regex

How to do explode except using ',' but not inside quote and double quote?

This is the string i want to explode:

```
`ot_request_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`ot_hours` int(11) NOT NULL,`ot_timelog_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`ot_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`ot_filing_date` datetime NOT NULL,`ot_approveby_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`final_approved` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' , `ot_token` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'Your, name, here' NOT NULL,`startTime` datetime NOT NULL,`endTime` datetime NOT NULL
```

I want the output to become

```
`ot_request_id` int(11) NOT NULL `ot_request_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ot_hours` int(11) NOT NULL ,
`ot_timelog_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ot_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ot_filing_date` datetime NOT NULL,
`ot_approveby_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`final_approved` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,
`ot_token` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'Your, name, here' NOT NULL,
`startTime` datetime NOT NULL,
`endTime` datetime NOT NULL
```

here is my code:

```
$array = explode(",",$str);// change to Regex
foreach($array as $m){
    echo "<br>$m";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex:

```
(?<=,)(?=(?:(?:[^`'"]*[`'"]){2})*[^`'"]*$)
```

It covers ' "  and ` as quote

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i0pbEz/6)

Sample Source ( [run here](http://ideone.com/Fz4Isp) )

```
$re = '/(?<=,)(?=(?:(?:[^`\'"]*[`\'"]){2})*[^`\'"]*$)/m';

$str = '`ot_request_id` int(11) NOT NULL `ot_request_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`ot_hours` int(11) NOT NULL,`ot_timelog_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`ot_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`ot_filing_date` datetime NOT NULL,`ot_approveby_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`final_approved` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT \'0\' ,
`ot_token` varchar(100) DEFAULT \'Your, name, here\' NOT NULL,`startTime` datetime NOT NULL,`endTime` datetime NOT NULL';


$keywords = preg_split($re,$str);
print_r($keywords);
```

It will output:

```
Array ( [0] => `ot_request_id` int(11) NOT NULL `ot_request_id` int(11) NOT NULL, [1] => `ot_hours` int(11) NOT NULL, [2] => `ot_timelog_id` int(11) NOT NULL, [3] => `ot_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL, [4] => `ot_filing_date` datetime NOT NULL, [5] => `ot_approveby_id` int(11) NOT NULL, [6] => `final_approved` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' , [7] => `ot_token` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'Your, name, here' NOT NULL, [8] => `startTime` datetime NOT NULL, [9] => `endTime` datetime NOT NULL )
```

Comment: Nice. This is what exactly what i need. I do it this way in php: $arrayQuery = preg_split("/(?<=,)(?=(?:(?:[^`'\"]*[`'\"]){2})*[^`'\"]*$)/",$query);

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of identifying the correct pattern-matching logic to achieve the desired result.

Using REGEX (`explode()` does not use REGEX - it splits on a string token), we can target only those commas which are proceeded by `.

```
$array = preg_split('/,(?= ?`)/', $str);
```

Note we also allow for an optional space between , and `.

Answer (score 0):

A bit different from your question about "between quotes": it seems de comma to break on, is always before a backtic (or white space followed by backtic)

```
<?php
$s = "`ot_request_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`ot_hours` int(11) NOT NULL,`ot_timelog_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`ot_user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`ot_filing_date` datetime NOT NULL,`ot_approveby_id` int(11) NOT NULL,`final_approved` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' , `ot_token` varchar(100) DEFAULT 'Your, name, here' NOT NULL,`startTime` datetime NOT NULL,`endTime` datetime NOT NULL";

$b = preg_replace('#,\s*`#', '[BR]`', $s);

$answer = explode('[BR]', $b);
print_r($answer);
```

would be easier when the whitespace would not be there (at ot_token)

note: preg_split() would avoid the extra step inserting a [BR] only to explode on it the next line: better use preg_split as already answered

Answer (score 0):

Although answered and accepted (because I worked on it for some time) I'll submit my answer, since it handles some things the accepted answer doesn't.

Using

`(?<=,)(?!\R)(?=(?:[^'"]*(['"])(?:\\.|(?!\1).)*\1)*[^'"]*$)`

to explode your string should do it. It fi

It Matches the position after a comma, **that isn't** followed by a linefeed (the negative look-ahead `(?!\R)`), **and is** followed by

1. a sequence of zero or more characters that doesn't contain a quote

   `[^'"]*`
2. a quote character that is captured

   `(['"])`
3. either an escaped character

   `\\.`

   or a character that doesn't match the captured quote, tested with a negative look-ahead.

   `(?!\1).`

   1 to 3 are in a non capturing group that can repeat any number of times (including zero).
4. finally it's ended by a sequence of zero or more characters that doesn't contain a quote. `$` (matches *end of line*) to make sure the whole string is matched.

   `[^'"]*$`

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iHnh7B/3).

Note that this solution assumes opening/closing quotes are balanced in the string (unless *in* a quoted string).

The things handled that aren't in the accepted answer is

1. single quoted strings **inside** a double quoted string, and vice versa.

   e.g. `"It's a solution"`
2. escaped characters in a string

   e.g. `'It\'s a solution'`

This may be completely unnecessary, but it was in my mindset when I started fiddling with this, so :)

Comment: Why not try to base your pattern on a `(*SKIP)(*F)` construct? I think it will be much more efficient.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Quite frankly, being a regex "newbie",  I'm not knowledgeable enough in the php/PCRE inner workings. And besides, I always strive to make a "flavor independent" (if there's such a thing) solution, unless performance is specifically a request/matter. But I can see why you wonder - my proposed solution **is** expensive performance-wise.